# iOSアプリからサーバ上のDBにデータを送信できない件

Tags: php, objective-c

開発初心者の質問で分かりにくい点が多々あるかと存じますが、ご了承くださいませ。
「Objective-C」にて「AFNetworking3.0」のライブラリを活用して、サーバー上（centOS7)
にデータの送信を試みているのですが、Xcodeにて以下のエラーが発生して、データの送信ができません。エラーの原因と解決方法がお分かりになる方、ご教示頂きたく存じます。

> ■エラー内容（ビルド実行後に表示されたエラー）
>   omain=com.alamofire.error.serialization.response Code=-1011 "Request failed: internal server error (500)" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: internal server error (500), NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://xxx.xxx.xx.xxx/send_request.php, com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.data=<>, com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.response= { URL: http://xxx.xxx.xx.xxx/send_request.php } { Status Code: 500, Headers {
>       Connection =     (
>           close
>       );
>       "Content-Length" =     (
>           0
>       );
>       "Content-Type" =     (
>           "text/html; charset=UTF-8"
>       );
>       Date =     (
>           "Thu, 26 Jul 2018 05:59:04 GMT"
>       );
>       Server =     (
>           "Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) PHP/7.1.19"
>       );
>       "X-Powered-By" =     (
>           "PHP/7.1.19"
>       );
>   } }}

■Objective-C（ビルド実行した内容）

```
- (void)send_request
{
AFHTTPSessionManager* manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
NSDictionary* postparam = @{ @"table_name" : @"test_json",
                             @"addtext1"   : @"add_A",
                             @"addtext2"   : @"add_B",
                             @"addtext3"   : @"add_C"};
[manager POST:@"http://XXX.XXX.XX.XXX/send_request.php"
   parameters:postparam progress:nil
      success:^(NSURLSessionTask* task, id responseObject) {
          //通信成功
          NSLog(@"成功response: %@", responseObject);
      }
      failure:^(NSURLSessionTask* operation, NSError* error) {
          //通信失敗
          NSLog(@"失敗Error: %@", error);
      }];
}
```

> 補足情報
>   データベース名：test
>   テーブル名：test_json
>   フィールド１：field_A
>   フィールド２：field_B
>   フィールド３：field_C
>   Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) 
>   PHP/7.1.19"
>   MySQL 5.7.22

■Databaseclass.php（サーバー上にアップしたファイル１）

```
<?php
mb_language("uni");
mb_internal_encoding("utf-8");
mb_http_input("auto");
mb_http_output("utf-8");
class Database{
var $dbServer;
var $dbName;
var $dbUser;
var $dbPass;
var $link;
var $db;
var $query;

function Database1($db_name)
{

    $this->dbServer="localhost";
    $this->dbName=$db_name;
    $this->dbUser="ユーザ名";
    $this->dbPass="パスワード";

    $this->link=mysql_connect($this->dbServer,
                              $this->dbUser,
                              $this->dbPass)
    or
    die(exit);

    $this->db=mysql_select_db($this->dbName,$this->link);

    $this->query=mysql_query('SET NAMES utf8',$this->link);
}

public function close()
{
    return mysql_close($this->link);
}

public function select($query)
{
    $result=mysql_query($query);
    $row=array();
    $row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    return $row;
}

public function query($query)
{
    return mysql_query($query);
}

public function jsonparse($query)
{
    $row = mysql_fetch_object($query);
    return $row;
}
}
?>
```

■send_request.php（サーバー上にアップしたファイル２）

```
<?php
include_once "DatabaseClass.php";

if($_POST["table_name"] && $_POST["addtext1"] 
&& $_POST["addtext2"] && $_POST["addtext3"])
{
$table_name = $_POST["table_name"];
$addtext1 = $_POST["addtext1"];
$addtext2 = $_POST["addtext2"];
$addtext3 = $_POST["addtext3"];

$database = new Database("test");

$sql = "INSERT INTO {$table_name} (field_A,field_B,field_C) VALUES ('{$addtext1}','{$addtext2}','{$addtext3}');";

$query = $database->query($sql);

$sql = ("SELECT * FROM {$table_name}");

$query = $database->query($sql);
$json= array();

if(strstr($table_name, 'test_json')){
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($query)) {
      $json[] = array(
         'field_A'=> $row->field_A
         ,'field_B'=> $row->field_B
         ,'field_C' => $row->field_C
      );
  }
}//if(strstr($table_name, 'test_json'))


header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
echo json_encode($json);

$database->close();

}//if($_POST["table_name"])
?>
```

Comment: `internal server error (500)`なので、サーバー側のエラー内容(エラーログなどから)を追記したほうが原因がわかりやすいと思います。

Comment: ご指摘頂き有難うございます。サーバー側のエラー内容確認致しました。以下エラーが発生するようで御座います。
Notice: Undefined index: table_name in /var/www/html/send_request.php on line 7

Comment: `Undefined index`については、 https://php1st.com/574/ が参考になるかもしれません。

Comment: ご教授頂き有難うございます。上記サイトを参考にphpファイルの先頭に if (isset($_POST["test"])) { echo $_POST["test"]; } を入れてみましたが、現象は解消されませんでした。しかしながら、貴重な情報を頂き有難うございました！

Comment: `Undefined index: table_name`なので、`$_POST["table_name"]`が送信されているかを確認する必要があると思います。

Comment: ご指摘有難うございます。
send_request.phpファイルの先頭に if (isset($_POST["table_name"])) { echo $_POST["table_name"]; } を追加後、xcodeにてビルド実行して、「send_request.php」をブラウザで開きエラー表示を確認しましたが、何も表示されませんでした。（このような確認方法で問題ないでしょうか）お手数をおかけ致します。

Comment: ぜんぜんPHPに詳しくないのですが、`print_r($_POST);`などにより、`$_POST`の内容を表示して、そこに`table_name`が存在するか確認すれば良いと思います。エラーの内容から考えると、クライアントから`table_name`が送付されていない可能性があります。

Comment: ご教示頂き有難う御座います。なるほどで御座います！貴重な情報有難う御座います！申し訳ございません。明日再度確認致します！本日は、ご教授頂き有難う御座いました。

Comment: 先日はご指摘有難うございました。print_r($_POST);をphpファイルに追加して動作を確認致しましたが、なぜかこのコードを追加すると、xcode側でエラーが発生するようで御座います。ログの取得方法、もう少し考えてみます！ご教授頂き有難うございました！

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHPのコードをざっと見た感じですが、コードに誤りがあります。

Databaseclass.phpの

```
function Database1($db_name)
```

は

```
function __construct($db_name)
```

だと思います。
send_request.phpの

```
$database = new Database("test");
```

でコンストラクタを呼び出そうとしているようですが、
コンストラクタの指定が適切ではないため、DBへの接続のコードが実行されていません。
直接の原因ではないかもしれませんが、参考にしてください。

あと、mysql_*系を利用されていますが、これらのコードは古いです。
PHP7以降では削除され、利用できなくなっているのでご注意ください。

以下「http://php.net/manual/ja/function.mysql-query.php」より

> 警告 この拡張モジュールは PHP 5.5.0 で非推奨になり、PHP 7.0.0 で削除されました。 MySQLi あるいは
>   PDO_MySQL を使うべきです。詳細な情報は MySQL: API の選択 や それに関連する FAQ を参照ください。
>   この関数の代替として、これらが使えます。
>
> mysqli_query() 
>   PDO::query()

ここまで書いて、環境の「PHP/7.1.19」に気が付きました。
上記の理由の通り、mysql_*系は削除され動作しません。
そのせいで500が出ている可能性が高いです。

Comment: 大変貴重なご指摘有難うございます！mysql_をmysqli_へすべて変更を致しました。「function __construct($db_name)」も修正し、エラーコード500は解消されました！xcodeも通信成功！となりました。しなしながら、DB側にはデータが届かず仕舞いで御座います。
php側のエラーは、「Notice: Undefined index: table_name in /var/www/html/send_request.php on line 9」と表示されます。
９行目は、
if($_POST["table_name"] && $_POST["addtext1"] && $_POST["addtext2"] && $_POST["addtext3"])
ですが、特に問題ないような気が致します。
あと一歩のような気が致しますが、今一度、全ソース確認致します。
３日ほどこのDBで足止めとなっておりまして。。ご教授頂き有難うございます！その他、なにかご指摘箇所等御座いましたら、よろしくお願い致します！

Comment: send_request.phpの「<?php
include_once "DatabaseClass.php";」

の個所を

「<?php
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
var_dump($_POST);
exit(0);

include_once "DatabaseClass.php";」

に変更して実行してみたら何か結果が出力されませんか？。

Comment: 失礼致しました。以下の結果が表示されました。

//ini_set("display_errors", 1); //error_reporting(E_ALL); array(0) { }

Comment: データが何もPOSTされていませんね。var_dump($_POST):をvar_dump($_GET);に変更してもう一度やってみてください。あと、 //ini_set("display_errors", 1); //error_reporting(E_ALL); の2行は<?php ... ?>の外に書いてますね。json形式でデータを返却しようとするとエラーになるので、<?php ... ?>内に記述してあげてください

Comment: var_dump($_GET);に変更して確認致しました。同様のエラーが発生致します。
//ini_set("display_errors", 1); //error_reporting(E_ALL); array(0) { }

先程もですが、「<?php header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8"); var_dump($_POST); exit(0); include_once "DatabaseClass.php";」に変更致しますと、xcodeにて「Code=-1016」エラーが発生致するようで御座います。

Comment: コードについて御座いますが、<?php ... ?>内に記述は致しております。ご指摘有難うございます。

Comment: //ini_set("display_errors", 1); //error_reporting(E_ALL); の2行が結果として出力されているのでてっきり<?php ... ?>外に記述されているものと思っていました。現状で考えられる原因は、「ライブラリが古い」「ライブラリの使い方が誤っている」「ライブラリ内部に不具合がある」のいずれかではないでしょうか。ライブラリ＝AFHTTPSessionManagerです。

Comment: PHPには問題がないという事で御座いますね！お時間頂き有難うございました。これだけ分かっただけでも、大変助かりました！ライブラリーを今一度入れ直して、再度確認致します。ご教授頂き有難うございました！

Comment: PHPのif分内部が実行されていない様なので絶対大丈夫とは言えません。あとSQLインジェクションの脆弱性がありますが、それについては別途お調べください。

Comment: ご指摘有難うございます。SQLインジェクションの脆弱性についても調査致します！貴重な情報頂き有難うございます！

Comment: user17014様、以下URLにて、user17014様よりご回答頂きました内容を元にこちらも無事解決致しました。有難うございました！大変助かりました！https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/47181/ios%e3%82%a2%e3%83%95%e3%82%9a%e3%83%aa%e3%81%8b%e3%82%89%e3%82%b5%e3%83%bc%e3%83%8f%e3%82%99%e4%b8%8a%e3%81%aedb%e3%81%ab%e3%83%86%e3%82%99%e3%83%bc%e3%82%bf%e3%82%92%e9%80%81%e4%bf%a1%e3%81%97%e3%81%9f%e9%9a%9b%e3%81%aephp%e3%82%a8%e3%83%a9%e3%83%bc%e3%81%ae%e4%bb%b6